# WinPrefetchView GUI

Tags: prefetch

I am wondering within the windprefetchview, when looking at the information in the GUI for the .pf file, what is the index column really used for?

Learning in class, wondering if there is an easy answer, can't find it on the web.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.